# Не могу сделать инсерт массива строк javax.persistence.EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

Вобщем заюзал ОРМ в проекте и вроде все инсертит селектит. Но есть проблема. Если я хочу заинсертить скопом массив строк вылетает ошибка.

```
public EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("COLIBRI").createEntityManager();
public void insertAVAYAcmCDRs(List<AvayaCmCdr> cdrList) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for (AvayaCmCdr aCdrList : cdrList) {
            em.persist(aCdrList);
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

но если инсерчу по одной строке все нормально

```
public void insertAVAYAcmCDRs(List<AvayaCmCdr> cdrList) {
        for (AvayaCmCdr avayaCmCdr : cdrList) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(avayaCmCdr);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
```

пробовал разные примеры типо

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
      Point point = new Point(i, i);
      em.persist(point);
      if ((i % 10000) == 0) {
          em.flush();
          em.clear();
      }
  }
  em.getTransaction().commit();
```

и другие варианты ничего не помогает. вылетает ошибка
на строке `em.persist(aCdrList);`

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

Comment: `SQLGrammarException` означает, что Hibernate послал серверу неправильный SQL запрос. В трассе стека должна быть запись `caused by` содержащая исключение с описанием проблемы. Приведите всю трассу стека, возможно конфиг hibernate.

Comment: [2015-11-30T14:20:01.330+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [AVAYAcmCDRParseManager] [tid: _ThreadID=124 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool5] [timeMillis: 1448871601330] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Exception in  task AVAYAcmCDRParseManager.ParseNewCDRs() time=30.11.15 14:20. Exception message = org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement.]]


все что есть в логах

Comment: Настройте `hibernate.show_sql=true`(это в дата соурс или же прям при создании сессионФактори) и в логах появится SQL который хибернейт посылает и уже смотрите в чем он не правильный.

Comment: А помоему проблема в конкретной строке, которую вы хотите закомитить. ParseNewCDRs() time=30.11.15 14:20. Проверьте лучше корректность данных.