# Как пропустить ошибку EntityExistsException при вставке строки в БД

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть метод которым я пытаюсь проинсертить табличку. Вот он:

```
public void insertAVAYAcmCDRs(List<AvayaCmCdr> cdrList) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for (AvayaCmCdr aCdrList : cdrList) {
            try {
                em.persist(aCdrList);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception in  task time={0}. Exception message = {1}.", new Object[]{aCdrList.getDate(), e.getMessage()});
            }
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.clear();
    }
```

Но он мне выкидывает ошибку. Работал нормально и вставил больше миллиона строк и упал. Я даже знаю почему. Я в базе создал индекс уникальный, который запрещает вставку одинаковых строк. Это работает. Я пытаюсь вставить дважды строку мне падает предупреждение что типо нельзя. Но в джаве на это же действие падает исключение и все обрывается. Я хочу же при такой ошибке просто пропустить эту строку и продолжить вставку, но не знаю как. Вот сама ошибка:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:
```

Может она и изза других причин я незнаю но думаю изза этого. Падает на втором шаге цикла. я вывел этот объект и в базе нашел его копию. тоесть он уже есть там и я птаюсь вставить такую же строку. Мне  MSSQL выдает ошибку, я ее получаю на сервере и все падает.

ДОБАВЛЯЮ

до строки `em.getTransaction().commit();` не доходит

Comment: Скорее всего надо обернуть в блок `try` строку  `em.getTransaction().commit()` и обработать исключение

Comment: На какой строке падает там и вставьте обработчик ошибки.

Comment: Тоесть сейчас вы в уже существующую таблицы загоняете новые данные?

Comment: Как мне кажется, автору нужен `merge` вместо `persist`, но я не настолько знаком с JPA, чтобы про это написать. И выглядит, как дубль http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470648/